# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop freezes after opening IntelliJ PHPStorm or WebStorm twice

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intellij

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and looks great, but after installing IntelliJ PHPStorm and WebStorm I can open one app (ie: WebStorm), but if I try to open the second app (ie: PHPStorm), or try to close and reopen the same app (ie: WebStorm) the desktop hangs up!

I can move the mouse but the desktop gets freezed! Can't open anything, can't switch windows, nothing!

I have a GeForce GTX660TI so I have installed nvidia 390 drivers from graphics PPA and it didn't solved the issue, it just got worse, because if I try to go back to nouveau drivers, I can't even boot, the screen gets black!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a issue that seems to be related to the bundled JDK. It recently got worse on the latest update.

What I do and sometimes it works, other times it does not is to restart the GPU:
`sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm ; sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm`,

then restart the sddm:
`sudo /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`

and restart plasmashell:
`killall plasmashell && plasmashell > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown`.

I have been facing this issue for the past 2 years (or something) and on latest Ubuntu 19 its way worse.

I have updated NVidia to 
 `| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       |
 |  Driver Version: 440.64 |
 |  CUDA Version: 10.2     |`

and its reaching a point where the OS is practically un-usable when WebStorm/Goland are running.

The best config I got so far was Ubuntu 18 with NVIDIA 390, so I would recommend you to not update nvidia drivers so fast.